# {Selenium & Java} How do I send a user name to hotmail user name field?

Tags: selenium, java

How do I send a user name to hotmail user name field? Do I need to focus 1st and then use sendKey option? I am also struggling to figure out how to use xpath or cssselector for this field.

https://login.live.com/

```
<div class="placeholder has-focus" aria-hidden="true" 
     style="cursor:text" 
     data-bind="text: hintText, css: hintCss">Email, phone, or Skype name
</div>
```

Your help/suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use sendkeys, No need to first set focus on the email field:
Below is the required xpath:

```
.//*[@id='CredentialsInputPane']//div[3]//div[2]/div
```

You can always use firepath addon in firefox, to take help, with creation of xpaths.